# More elegant way to define slanted triangle wave?

Tags: functions, piecewise-continuity

I've created this function (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3uwpld1lqb):

$$\mathrm{saw}(x, q) = x-\lfloor x \rfloor$$

$$\mathrm{slantedTriangle}(x,q) = \dfrac{|\mathrm{saw}\left(x-q\right)-1+q|}{\{\mathrm{saw}\left(x-q\right)-1+q>0:q,1-q}$$

But don't like that $\mathrm{saw}\left(x-q\right)-1+q$ is repeated, nor do I like the use of a piecewise expression. Are there any tricks that can make it look nicer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an interesting way to plot a slanted triangle wave:

$$
y = 2 \left\lvert x - py - \left\lfloor x - py + \frac12 \right\rfloor \right\rvert.
\tag1
$$

When $p = 0$ this produces a symmetric triangle wave.
If you let $-\frac12 \leq p \leq \frac12$ you can get the same kinds of plots that you get with $\mathrm{slantedTriangle}(x,q)$ with $0 \leq q \leq 1,$
except that at $p = \pm\frac12,$ Equation $(1)$ plots vertical line segments connecting the tops and bottoms of the diagonal segments,
whereas at $q = 0$ and $q = 1$, $\mathrm{slantedTriangle}(x,q)$ produces only the diagonal segments.

Moreover, if you let $p$ range over all real numbers, you can get some **very** slanted triangles which cannot be plotted by setting $y$ to a function of $x.$

---

The ideas behind this are first of all that you can get a sawtooth function
from $y = x - \lfloor x \rfloor.$
But if you generalize this to $$y = x - \lfloor x + s \rfloor,$$
the diagonal segments of the function are shifted down and to the left by
$s$ horizontal units and $s$ vertical units.
If you set $s = \frac12$ the segments are exactly half above the $x$ axis and half below; take the absolute value and you get a triangle wave.
Multiply by $2$ so that the peaks of the triangles reach the line $y = 1.$
That is, the symmetric case of your triangle wave can be plotted by

$$ y = 2 \left\lvert x - \left\lfloor x + \frac12 \right\rfloor \right\rvert. $$

Now to get the "slant", we can apply a shear transformation of the plane that leaves the $x$ axis fixed:
$(x,y) \to (x + py, y).$
In order to apply this transformation to the graph, we apply the inverse transformation to the variables of the graph's equation:
$(x,y) \to (x - py, y).$

That is, replace $x$ by $x - py$ in the equation.
This shifts each point of the graph $py$ units to the right
(that is, the amount of the shift depends on the height above the $y$ axis),
for the same reason that replacing $x$ by $x - b$ in the equation of a graph
shifts the entire graph $b$ units to the right.

Comment: Oooh! I like this. Thank you for the equation and for explaining the ideas behind it :)